# How to drag and drop a div onto another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Right now my program can dynamically create rows of squares (2 rows of 12). When you double click on one of the squares, a color picker will pop up and then you can specify the color for that square.

However, I am trying to also implement a "shortcut" so that if you drag an already colored square onto another one, that new square will also be colored.

What I have done so far:

http://codepen.io/blazerix/pen/rrwPAK

```
var id_num = 1;
var picker = null;
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', ".repeat", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.parent();
    if($self.hasClass("add-bottom")){
      $parent.after($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;

    } else {
      $parent.before($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;
    }
});   
});

$(".startLEDs").draggable({
revert:true
});
```

I have tried to use the draggable feature from JQuery but noticed that when I try to drag the boxes, the entire div disappears. And, also I only want the boxes to be draggable and droppable, nothing else.

Any help or feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. What exactly is not working? How do you expect it to be working?

Comment: @Twisty So if you comment out the draggable code i added, you'll notice that if you double click on a box, a color picker will pop up and you can just select a color. I'm trying to make it so that once a color is chosen for a particular box, the user can just drag that color onto another box, instead of having to go through the color picker again.

Comment: Ok, so if there is no color, it should not be draggable. If a color is selected, that color could be dragged to another to replicate the color to that target as an alternate method to coloring. Is this it?

Comment: @Twisty yes exactly

Comment: Should this be limited to only dragging a color to a nearby item or an item in a whole other color group?

Comment: @Twisty So one "object" is considered to be the two rows of boxes (plus the add buttons and input form). I'm trying to make it so that it can be either object only scope. However, if it is easier to implement it so that you can drag a box's color from any object, I wouldn't mind having that functionality.

Comment: It's a matter of drag containment. Sounds like you would prefer to be able to drag to either, so I will give you an example of that.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you! Please include it in an answer (instead of comments) so I can rep you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have so far, but due to the `id` attributes not being unique after cloning, it has some quirks.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/aqfn34bs/

**HTML**

```
<div class="bottomdiv">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="repeatable-0">
      <button class="repeat add-top">Add above</button>
      <ul class="repeatable">
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED1"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED2"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED3"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED4"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED5"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED6"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED7"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED8"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED9"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED10"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED11"></li>
        <li class="startLEDs" id="sLED12"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED1"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED2"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED3"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED4"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED5"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED6"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED7"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED8"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED9"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED10"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED11"></li>
        <li class="endLEDs" id="eLED12"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="timeMilli">Time(ms):
        <input type="text" name="time" form="form1">
      </div>
      <button class="repeat add-bottom">Add below</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was looking at using `sortable`, and so I switched it to a unorganized list in my testing and then went back to `draggable` but still licked the list of colors versus links. I suspect you could revert back if you desired.

**CSS**

```
div.bottomdiv {
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 60px;
  float: left
}

.timeMilli {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.repeatable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 408px;
}

ul.repeatable li {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

b {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.repeat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.repeat > * {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

Minor changes here for `ul` and `li`.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  function setColor(obj, r) {
    obj.css('background-color', r);
    obj.attr("data-color", r);
  }

  function makeDrag(obj) {
    obj.draggable({
      helper: "clone",
      opacity: 0.85
    });
  }

  function makeDrop(obj) {
    obj.droppable({
      accept: ".repeatable li",
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.helper.data("color")) {
          setColor($(this), ui.helper.data("color"));
          makeDrag($(this));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).on('click', ".repeat", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.parent();
    var id_num = $("div[id^='repeatable']").length;
    if ($self.hasClass("add-bottom")) {
      $parent.after($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable-" + id_num));
      makeDrop($("#repeatable-" + id_num + " .repeatable li"));
      makeDrag($("#repeatable-" + id_num + " .repeatable li[data-color^='#']"));
    } else {
      $parent.before($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable-" + id_num));
      makeDrop($("#repeatable-" + id_num + " .repeatable li"));
      makeDrag($("#repeatable-" + id_num + " .repeatable li[data-color^='#']"));
    }
  });

  $(".repeatable li").on("dblclick", function(e) {
    $(this).spectrum({
      color: "#f00",
      change: function(color) {
        setColor($(this), color.toHexString());
        makeDrag($(this));
      }
    });
  });

  makeDrop($(".repeatable li"));
});
```

I didn't see a need for the `id_num` and `picker` variables in global.

Since we will be making a number of things change colors, draggable, and droppable, I created functions to do this repeatedly.

So draggable by itself would not accomplish what you needed. You need droppable to be able to action things when the dragged item is dropped. For example, it has an `out` and `over` event that you could color the box it's over while it's over it, and then revert the color once dragged out.

For now, we stick to basics: we set a color with a Double Click event, we can then drag that color to another nearby box, and the color for that box is set to the same color when dropped.

Now if we clone things before or after, things get sticky. Will look over it later, but this should get you moving forward for now.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Yes, because of the non-unique ids I had to shuffle through many colorPickers because it would only recognize the first object that I modified.

Comment: Might consider not using `id` attributes on those. Otherwise you'd clear them and create new unique ones each time they are cloned.